# Why my code doesn't pick correct IP address ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, network-programming

I am using this to pick my system's current IP address (*which is set to dynamic*) but it picks only this `::1` ? but I want to pick a full IP address like `192.168.1.56` etc

Code I have used:

```
string UserIPAddress = Page.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: Then access your website with the full IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: What if my project is deployed on realtime server with same code, would it pick real IP address instead of ::1 ?

Comment: Did you read the question that this one has just been marked a duplicate of?

Comment: Yes but I am too new to understand those details, in first semester, if you could just tell me ?

Comment: That would I get IP address if same code is deployed on realtime server